# Run an applet like to a process?

Tags: java, applet

Hi 
I want create an applet, and when I'm running it don't  show anything but it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an applet white on a white background and 1 pixel by 1 pixel.

Comment: When you embed the applet inside the browser appletviewer should not be shown